Did Original Sin derive solely from Adam or from both Adam and Eve?
Pohle, God the Author of Nature and the Supernatural pt. 2, ch. 2, §3, art. 4, 1. claims:

It is a controverted question among theologians whether [1] original sin derives solely from Adam or [2] from both Adam and Eve as its efficient cause

Which theologians held position #1, and which held position #2?
Position #1 would seem to imply that Eve never had Original Sin, though she certainly committed an actual sin (of pride) by transgressing God's command.
Position #2 would have to explain how Eve inherited or shared in Adam's sin.
I'm not asking whether Adam or Eve is more culpable, but whether Adam alone or Adam with Eve is the cause of their children inheriting Original Sin.

Your link seems to have a Java problem. This one works better Doctrine of Original Sin etc.

My answer to your linked question answers your question: Is Adam or Eve more culpable for original sin? I think your question could be a duplicate!

Why doesn't this conclusively answer the question?  "Wherefore, as by one man sin entered into the world..." Romans 5:12a.  Are you asking after a Catholic response by using the Catholicism tag or is it just that Pohle is Catholic.

This article explains Saint Anselm's view. Original sin is not passed biologically, but spiritually. https://www.anselm.edu/sites/default/files/Documents/Institute%20of%20SA%20Studies/4.5.3.2i_21McMahon.pdf

@MikeBorden If only Adam sinned, how does Eve "catch" Original Sin from him? Or is her personal sin of pride (not Original Sin) the cause of her punishment (Gen. 3:16)?

One way might be that she was taken out of him when she was formed.  All are either in Adam or in Christ.  I believe the idea is called Natural Headship although Federal Headship is another valid explanation.  I don't think we are supposing that Eve did not sin, just that her sin did not constitute the fall of man.  " How does Eve "catch" Original Sin from Adam" would be an excellent question if it could be scoped properly.

While Eve also participated in the fall, the Church teaches that Adam’s role was primary in transmitting original sin. Eve’s sin contributed to the fallen state of humanity, but it is Adam’s sin that affects all of their descendants.

Yes, I know, but how does Eve "catch" Original Sin from Adam?

@Geremia 'As in Adam, all die . . . . .  ' Scripture states something (Adam sinned and all die - including Eve) and you are demanding a mechanism which scripture does not convey. This is a matter of God's own righteous judgment. He decides.

Did Original Sin derive solely from Adam or from both Adam and Eve?
The great St. Thomas Aquinas states in his Summa that Adam was responsible for transmitting Original sin to the entire human race and not Eve:
The solution of this question is made clear by what has been said. For it has been stated that original sin is transmitted by the first parent in so far as he is the mover in the begetting of his children: wherefore it has been said that if anyone were begotten materially only, of human flesh, they would not contract original sin. Now it is evident that in the opinion of philosophers, the active principle of generation is from the father, while the mother provides the matter. Therefore original sin, is contracted, not from the mother, but from the father: so that, accordingly, if Eve, and not Adam, had sinned, their children would not contract original sin: whereas, if Adam, and not Eve, had sinned, they would contract it. - Whether if Eve, and not Adam, had sinned, their children would have contracted original sin?

Is this based on the incorrect scientific understanding of human generation in Aquinas' day?

Yes, but was it Eve's actual sin of pride (not Original Sin) that caused her (and future women's) punishment (Gen. 3:16)?
